READ_SMS permission is not working in react native
I am coding a new react native app where I need READ_SMS permission. Following is my code --
  const requestSmsPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const hasPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_SMS)
      if (hasPermission) {
        console.log("hasPermission")
        return;
      }

      console.log("not Has permission")

      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_SMS,
        {
          title: 'SMS Permission',
          message:
            'SMS PERMISSION',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        }
      );

      console.log('Permission Given')

      return granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.granted

    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error requesting permission:', err);
      return false;
    }
  }

I am triggering this function on a button click event. In the terminal only not Has permission consoles, after that no activity happens in my app. Ideally a popup of granting sms should appear.
I tested this code with CAMERA permission and it works but not for READ_SMS.
I have also added the below code in my AndroidManifest.xml file.
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

I am expecting to see a popup when i trigger this function.
